# String variable as input for functions

Tags: c++

I have a function

```
getText();
```

it works this way

```
getText("This is a really nice text");
```

but it does not work this way

```
std:string myString = "Also a nice text";
getText(myString);
```

Why?

Comment: you didn't say how is `getText` declared, I guess it is `void getText(const char*)`

Comment: "I have a function `getText();`" - that's not a function. that's a *function call*. where's your function? or at least, the signature...

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but the namespace separator is `::` not `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your function declaration may be like this  =>  " getText(char *parameter)"

if your function declaration is like this   => " getText(std::string parameter) "

it should be working